# WPF application closes when calling `.ShowDialog()` of a popup windows

Tags: c#, wpf

First I want to explain what I'm going to do: I'm developing a Learning application to show some cards to the students. I have `CardPack` class that is a group of cards.

For licensing the card packs I want to get an ID from user then I've created a windows to get RegisterKey from user. this is my `GetRegisterKey("CardPackName")` method:

```
    public static string GetRegisterKey(string name)
    {
        GetRegisterKey grk = new GetRegisterKey(name);
        grk.ShowDialog();
        return grk.Key;
    }
```

but after `grk.ShowDialog();` runs the program going to exit and I don't know why! **Can anybody help me to resolve this problem?!?**

---

**Update**

I tried to create a new instance of `GetRegisterKey` in `Windows_loaded` event of `MainWindows` and I called `grk.ShowDialog()` and it worked fine and the program didn't close. I don't know what's the source of my problem!

But I found out that the problem isn't from `GetRegisterKey` then I'll remove it's code from the question.

**Update2**

I put a break point in `return grk.Key;` line to check if it runs but it didn't run and the program closed!

Comment: Are you using mutiple threads?

Comment: Are you using StartupUri in App.xaml or are you using Application.Run method? In either case if your GetRegistryKey dialog is used then your application will shut down. It means your GetRegistryKey is the MainDialog of the application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See Application.ShutDownMode,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx

Applications stop running only when the Shutdown method of the Application is called. Shut down can occur implicitly or explicitly, as specified by the value of the ShutdownMode property.

If you set ShutdownMode to OnLastWindowClose, Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) implicitly calls Shutdown when the last window in an application closes, even if any currently instantiated windows are set as the main window (see MainWindow).

A ShutdownMode of OnMainWindowClose causes Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) to implicitly call Shutdown when the MainWindow closes, even if other windows are currently open.

The lifetime of some applications may not be dependent on when the main window or last window is closed, or may not be dependent on windows at all. For these scenarios you need to set the ShutdownMode property to OnExplicitShutdown, which requires an explicit Shutdown method call to stop the application. Otherwise, the application continues running in the background.

ShutdownMode can be configured declaratively from XAML or programmatically from code.

This property is available only from the thread that created the Application object.

Comment: I added `ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"` to my `app.xml` as [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) said. but the problem doesn't resolved and program close after `GetRegisterKey` runs!

Comment: run it with through debugger. It might be those weird string symbols you are using. I can't tell you more becase the code itself looks okay.

Comment: I tried it. but after the constructor of the popup runs the program going to close!

Answer (score 2):

Can you subscribe to following events in App.xaml.cs for debugging purpose? It will help you checking stack trace and find if any unhandled exception causing this issue.

```
 public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.DispatcherUnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(App_DispatcherUnhandledException);
        this.Exit += new ExitEventHandler(App_Exit);
    }

    void App_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check stack trace.
    }

    void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if this event handler get executed and from where control is coming to this method.
    }
}
```

Comment: there isn't any `DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler` and `DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs` in the default namespaces! can you tell me the namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how did you open the `GetRegistryKey` window but here is what I think. You can either set `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` from `App.xaml` file or you can disable it by writing your own Main method and call for `application.Run(new MainWindow())`. But, for either case you would have `MainWindow` opened and prevented your registry window.

So, I guess you somehow created your `GetRegistryKey` window before your `MainWindow` class. And as far as I am aware application claims the first created window as its main window. Therefore, you need to set `Application.Current.MainWindow` before you close.

Comment: If you didn't change any default configurations, then Zahir is correct, GetRegistryKey is set as your MainWindow and once closed, it will close you app, so for better answers, provide the MainWindow xaml and cs files.

Comment: @MohsenAfshin I didn't change any default configurations but program going to close after `GetRegistrKey` opens. It close automatically and I don't know why!

Comment: Try to create another window, instantiate it and call ShowDialog on that, check whether it closes your app again or not. If yes, then the problem is not with your GetRegisterKey but with you caller window (MainWindow). If not, then the problem is with GetRegisterKey, so open another instance of VS, create a new Project add copy paste the GetRegisterKey from Solution Explorer to your new project and check the functionality.

Comment: If your MainWindow code is not so much, I suggest to create another project and copy paste your MainWindow code there, create a button and inside it's click window show GetRegisterKey. See if it works