# MainWindow gets closed when closing ChildWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am developing a wpf application for the surface pro in tablet mode. I am coding on a different computer and there everything works fine. When testing the application on the surface pro something weird happens:

During the application a second window gets opened, in order to modify some settings. This window includes a button in order to close the window (see code below). When this button is clicked on the surface pro the whole application gets closed (including the main window). On the computer where I am writing the code this never happens, so in my opinion the problem lies with the hardware.

Thank you for your help!

#### Edit 21/03/2018

So as discussed in the comments I have tried several things and the problem remains. I have now deleted most of the application code such that only the essential feature remain and the problem still hasn't disappeared. I will post the code below:

### App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="TestNamespace.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestNamespace"
         Startup="ApplicationStartup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

### App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    public MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    public Monitoring monitoring;

    private void ApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        window.Show();
        monitoring = new Monitoring();

        window.Content = monitoring.gui;
        this.DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
        this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;
     }

    private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("App1: There has been an unhandled exception");
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("App2: There has been an unhandled exception");
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

### GUI.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestNamespace.GUI"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
         xmlns:mi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestNamespace">
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Width="300" Height="300"
                Content="NewWindow" Click="SettingsButton_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### GUI.xaml.cs

```
public partial class GUI : UserControl
{ 
    private Monitoring monitoring;

    public GUI(Monitoring monitoring)
    {
        this.monitoring = monitoring;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;
    }

    private void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" GUI: There has been an unhandled exception");
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void SettingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        monitoring.settingsWindow = new testWindow();
        monitoring.settingsWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

### Monitoring.cs

```
public class Monitoring
{
    private App currentApp = (App)Application.Current;
    public GUI gui;
    public Window settingsWindow;

    public Monitoring()
    {
        gui = new GUI(this);
    }
}
```

### TestWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestNamespace.testWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestNamespace"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="testWindow" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="245,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### TestWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class testWindow : Window
{
    public testWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;
    }

    private void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TestWindow: There has been an unhandled exception");
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestNamespace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestNamespace"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="47" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="LOADING..." VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="198" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="36" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

This is the complete code for the  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. This code still produces the error on the tablet. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Create a [mcve] for this. It sounds implausible, maybe some exception terminates your app.

Comment: There is no exception that terminates the application, I have checked the Event Viewer in windows and under Application logs everything seems fine. Then I have installed remote debugging on the tablet in order to debug and still found nothing. On the Computer after calling this.close() it first calls unload event handlers of a 'userControl' and then returns to the main window and keeps running. On the tablet it doesn't even call the unload event handlers and it just ends. I have tried to build a minimal, complete and verifiable example, but the error did not show up. I am quite lost now.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I changed the new window to a lot simpler version. Do you need information about the main window as well? It is already a huge application with a lot of code.

Comment: It seems unlikely, since you already checked the Application logs, but maybe you could try to catch all unhandled exceptions and see if that shows anything: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: So I added e.Handled=true, I added handlers for 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.UnhandledException' and 'Application.DispatcherUnhandledException' and the problem still remains. Thank you for your support!

Comment: I do call settingsWindow.Show(), but I just tried it with ShowDialog() as well. It made no difference, but I agree ShowDialog would be better.
I run the application on the tablet (tablet-mode Off) through a remote debugger, such that I can set breakpoints. I have set breakpoints in every unhandled eventhandlers, so I can know that they didn't fire. In addition there has been no line written in the 'Debug' Output.

Comment: On my dev PC I cannot turn on Tablet-mode. It is disabled completely

Comment: I added an event handler for the exit event of the application and placed a breakpoint there. The application stopped at the breakpoint, so this handler is actually called. Does this help you?

Comment: But you really should start writing a [mcve]. Start wit 2 simple Windows and then making it more and more like your App (like that Monitoring class etc). heproblem is in something you haven't posted so far.

Comment: The e.ApplicationExitCode is 0.

Comment: And about the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: When I run this application, such as I posted it here, it still produces the error on the surface pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem! Instead of creating and showing a new window, I created a new UserControl (TestWindow) and changed the content of the mainWindow. Upon closing the TestWindow, the normal GUI is loaded as Content of the MainWindow and the TestWindow is set to null.

It might not be the best solution, but it works.

**EDIT 1**

A few weeks later I stumbled upon the same problem once again. I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12734413/7705525) written by Erti-Chris Eelmaa that finally solved the problem. I needed to change the `Application.ShutdownMode` such that the application only shuts down when `Application.Shutdown();` is explicitly called.

```
Application.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
```

I hope this helps!