# c# wpf Dialog will close the owner window

Tags: reactjs, c#, wpf

i have a window that is acting like a Dialog with two buttons and a textbox, so its an input dialog, the problem is when i press the buttons, or close the dialog window in any way the main window that i used to create this dialog will get closed too! (exit code = 0) and another thing is that it will work OK in vs debugging but when i run the app without vs debugging that owner window get closed and in my case that window is the Main app window so the whole application will shutdown! what am i doing wrong?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Server.Forms.Dialogs.PokeDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Server.Forms.Dialogs"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Poke" MinHeight="120" MinWidth="225"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    x:Name="windowPoke"
    Loaded="windowPoke_Loaded">
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="25">
    <Label Content="Poke Reason:"
           Padding="0"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textboxPokeReason"
             Margin="0 5"/>

    <DockPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnOk"
                Click="btnOk_Click"
                IsDefault="True"
                Content="OK"
                MinWidth="100"
                Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnCancel"
                Click="btnCancel_Click"
                IsCancel="True"
                Content="Cancel"
                MinWidth="100"/>
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
public partial class PokeDialog : Window
{
    public string PokeReason
    {
        get { return textboxPokeReason.Text; }
    }

    public PokeDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void windowPoke_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textboxPokeReason.Focus();
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = false;
    }
}
```

the way i used dialog:

```
private void btnPokeClient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new PokeDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TRUE - input text:" + dialog.PokeReason);
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("FALSE");
    }
```

i can see the messageboxes too, but after closing this message boxes the whole app will get closed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF application closes when calling \`.ShowDialog()\` of a popup windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734066/wpf-application-closes-when-calling-showdialog-of-a-popup-windows)

Comment: where to call btnPokeClient_Click，can you add the code